# Python Tornado XSRF cookie issue with Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, cookies, tornado

I am new to Tornado and I am trying to build a very simple login form with xsrf cookie.
Code as below:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")
    def post(self):
        self.write("You ahve submitted the form.!")
class App(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
        ]
        settings = dict(xsrf_cookies=True)
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    server.listen(7001)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

The form is also very simple:

```
<html>
<head><title>Text XSRF</title></head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    {% module xsrf_form_html() %}
    {% raw xsrf_form_html() %}
    Username:<input type="text" name="username">
    Password:<input type="password" name="pwd">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am adding to the host file a domain:

```
127.0.0.1 xsrf.test.com
```

And when I open Chrome and type in hxxp://xsrf.test.com:7001, I can see the login form, but when sending the POST request I get a

```
403 (XSRF cookie does not match POST argument)
```

However, if I hit hxxp://localhost:7001, I can submit the form as expected. IE and Safari works fine for both domains. So I am wondering is there anything I did wrong to make this work using "xsrf.test.com" in Chrome?

I did check *Chrome->Settings->Content Settings->Cookies->Allow local data to be set* is properly selected.

Comment: What does the form look like? Did you include `{% module xsrf_form_html() %}`?

Comment: @BenDarnell Added the form as requested, yes, I included it, otherwise it won't for other browsers.

Comment: I captured the network package and found the problem is indeed the "Set-Cookie" in response does not work for Chrome with a domain added to host file. But it works for Chrome using "localhost". I am a little bit confused now.